# Get the email of users in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a small google spreadsheets which multiple users are accessing and adding info in it. I've been trying to get the email of every user which edits a row but I can't seem to find out how it works! [In here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser()) it's written that I can do it with getActiveUser() function but when changes are made, it just leaves a blank cell on the row!

Here is what I've done so far:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  if( s.getName() == "Sources with Bugs" ) {                                       
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 2) {                                                      
      var userCell = r.offset(0, 4);
      userCell.setValue(email);
    }
  }
}
```

So as I said, basically if a user edits the 2nd column of any rows, the 6th column should be filled with the user's email! Anyone has any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @MaxMakhrov Yes but in there it says: allows a script to run without that user's authorization or "execute as me" (that is, authorized by the developer instead of the user) onEdit ! so basically when I allow, all users should be giving permission by my consent! isnt it?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to give a shot to `e.user.getEmail()` instead of `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` — for the reasons described on @Max Makhrov's link in the comment above.

Comment: Yea, I tried that too but i get the following: TypeError: Cannot read property "user" from undefined. (line x, file "Code")Dismiss

Comment: That would happen if you try to run `onEdit(e)` manually from the script editor. If you want to test the function, you should actually edit a cell in your sheet or look at this trick: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089041/how-can-i-test-a-trigger-function-in-gas